# Return a list of top tags for a user

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to retrieve a list of the top tags for a User using ElasticSearch and Tire.

I've seen [this article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/05/13/data-visualization-with-elasticsearch-and-protovis.html) floating around, however it doesn't completely work in my situation.

I need to filter by a user_id, and am aiming not to get hits returned at all. I haven't found a way of getting this to work with Tire.

I have tried the following:

```
Tire.search 'bookmarks' do |s|
  s.query { all }
  s.facet 'tags', facet_filter: { term: { user_id: 1 } } do
    terms :tags, all_terms: true
  end
end
```

Help is appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT:** Using the code above, the following output is returned.

```
=> #<Tire::Search::Search:0x007fd4b0bed110 @indices=["bookmarks"], 
   @types=[], @options={}, @path="/bookmarks/_search", 
   @query=#<Tire::Search::Query:0x007fd4b0bec5d0 @value={:match_all=>{}}>, 
   @facets={"tags"=>{:terms=>{:field=>:tags, :size=>10, :all_terms=>true}, 
   :facet_filter=>{:term=>{:user_id=>1}}}}>
```

**EDIT 2:** I've accomplished what I was trying to do with the following code:

```
# Public: Returns an array of hashes, which includes the user's top
# tags and a number of items in those tags.
#
# Format follows:
#   [{'term' => 'Some Tag', 'count' => 123}, {'term' => 'Another Tag', 'count' => 321}]
#
def self.top_tag_count(user_id, number_of_tags=10)
  top_tags = tire.search search_type: 'count' do |s|
    s.query { all }
    s.filter :term, user_id: [user_id]
    s.facet 'tags', global: true do
      terms :tags, size: number_of_tags
    end
  end
  top_tags.facets['tags']['terms']
end
```

Comment: I can't decipher the sentence "am aiming not to get hits returned at all".

Comment: "am aiming not to get hits returned at all" – What I meant was that, ideally, I'd not like ElasticSearch to return copies of my model (Bookmark) in the results. Although I don't know if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Tire [integration test](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/facets_test.rb) for facets contains a lot of examples of possible things.

You seem to be on a right way -- you didn't describe the output and what you'd like to see.

Comment: Ideally I'd like the output to contain the Top 10 tags for a User, based off of how many Bookmarks contain the tag. Using [the method](https://gist.github.com/3933213) in [this article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/05/13/data-visualization-with-elasticsearch-and-protovis.html) worked for me, however now I would like to facet the top tags by User.